# How can I redirect `time` output and command output to the same pipe?

Tags: shell, command-line, pipe, time-utility

Suppose I have a binary called `foo`.

If I want to redirect the output of `foo` to some other process `bar`, I could write `./foo | bar`.

On the other hand, if I wanted to `time` foo, and redirect the output of `time` I could write, `time (./foo) | bar`.

My question is, how can I stick the output of `time` to the end of the output of `foo` and pipe it through the *same pipe*?

The following solution is **not** what I am looking for, because it starts two separate instances of the process `bar`, while I want a single shared pipe, to a single instance of `bar`.

```
time (./foo | bar)  | bar
```

For anyone who is curious, the reason for not wanting to start two instances of `bar` is because `bar` can be a network client and I want the timing information to be sent to the server as part of the same `http POST` message as the process output.

Comment: answered here, somewhat better answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356628/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-the-time-command-to-a-file-in-linux

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking for I this will do. I'm using the commands `ls ~` and `tee` as stand-ins for `./foo` and `bar`, but the general form of what you want is this:

```
$ ( time ./foo ) |& bar
```

**NOTE:** The output of `time` is already being attached at the end of any output from `./foo`, it's just being done so on STDERR. To redirect it through the pipe you need to combine STDERR with STDOUT. You can use either `|&` or `2>&1` to do so.

```
$ ( time ./foo ) |& bar

-or-

$ ( time ./foo ) 2>&1 | bar
```

#### Example

```
$ ( time ls . ) |&  tee cmd.log
cmd.log
file1
file2
file3
file4
file5

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.001s
```

And here's the contents of the file `cmd.log` produced by `tee`.

```
$ more cmd.log 
cmd.log
file1
file2
file3
file4
file5

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Comment: Note that this syntax doesn't work for BASH.

Comment: @jvriesem all the examples are from bash

Comment: The `|&` operator is not recognized at least as of v3.2.57. The knowledge I gained from this is the parentheses were necessary and create a subshell.

Comment: `|&` shows up in Bash 4. Control operators is covered here BTW - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators.

Answer (score 12):

`time` sends its output to stderr instead of stdout by default.  You just need to redirect that where you want it.

You say *"On the other hand, if I wanted to `time` foo, and redirect the output of `time` I could write, `time (./foo) | bar`."* but this is actually incorrect.  In this case, the output of time would still be displayed on your console, only stdout would be redirected.

You can redirect stderr specifically with:

```
(time foo) 2>&1 | bar
```

or all pipes with:

```
(time foo) |& bar
```

The brackets are needed for this to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer helped me figure it out. The accepted answer mentions dollar sign in the beginning, I thought that's supposed to be part of the command and was confused why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this works on Solaris.
`(time ls) &> file`

Comment: This is no different to either of the existing solutions